# Convert DOMElement Array to jQuery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using the [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin for jQuery and need to get one of the table rows. DataTables has a fnGetNodes function that returns an Array with all of the DOMElements of the table. I would like to use a jQuery selector to find that row (I know the id of the row), but I need to convert the Array to a jQuery Object, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically you could do it with

```
var $row = $(dom_array).filter( 
               function(index){ 
                   return $(this).attr('id') == 'some_id'; 
               } 
           );
```

this will return a jQuery object of the row with the specified id.

Comment: I knew it had to be simple. I prefer using selectors though. So, I went with:

$(dom_array).filter('tr[id='+pid+']');

Answer (score 7):

To get a jQuery object from an Array of nodes, you can just pass it to jQuery:

```
var nodes = [document.documentElement, document.documentElement.firstChild];
var extendedNodes = $(nodes);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ you can do just that:

```
jQuery( elementArray )

elementArrayAn array containing a set of DOM elements to wrap in a jQuery object.
```

If it doesn't work, possibly your array is not an actual array, so you can try:

```
$('#id',$($.makeArray(array)));
```